# Adjusting the rectangle that maximized windows fit in?

Tags: c#, desktop, windows-desktop-gadgets

The best way I can think of to ask this is by example... In Windows 7 and Vista, there's the gadget bar down the right hand side of the screen, and when you maximize a different (any and all) window, that window fills the rest of the screen without covering the gadget bar. How can I do that with my own app except across the top of the screen in C#?

I want to write a ticker displaying information from social networking sites across the top of the screen but obviously I don't want to cover the min, max, and close buttons of maximized windows.

I guess what I'm asking is how do I change the Desktop Working Area and put my application just above the working area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this.  This is a non-trivial task.

However, there is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx) that does this in C#.  This should make it very easy to implement for a Windows Forms application.  If you want to use a different UI technology, you should be able to port the API calls.